# How to get a specific program from the task manager

Tags: batch

i want to get the process that is running with the GDI Object 157 using batch script command but not able to do so
my script is
tasklist /fi "gdiobject eq 157"

Answer (score 0):

Read whole `tasklist /?`: there are listed all allowed filters (only `11` filter names currently).

Moreover, you can't retrieve value of [Windows Task Manager `GDI Objects` column](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/task-manager-columns-windows-7-explained) using either command line utility `tasklist.exe` nor powershell cmdlet `Get-Process`. You need to compute it using [`GetGuiResources` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683192.aspx):

> Retrieves the count of handles to graphical user interface (GUI)
>   objects in use by the specified process.

Fortunately, there is a way to call native Windows APIs in Windows PowerShell: [`Add-Type` cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-6) can use the Platform Invoke (P/Invoke) mechanism to call a function in a `.dll` library from Windows PowerShell.

For instance, [*Example 5: **Call native Windows APIs***](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-6#examples) demonstrates it sufficiently to write the following simple script:

```
# GDI objects: get number of GDI handles per process

Add-Type -Name NativeMethods -Namespace Win32 -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int GetGuiResources(IntPtr hProcess, int uiFlags);
'@

$allProcesses = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcesses() #or# Get-Process
$auxCountHandles = [int]0
$auxCountProcess = [int]0
$GuiResources = @()
ForEach ($p in $allProcesses) {
        if ( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty( $p.Handle)) { continue }
        $auxCountProcess += 1
        $auxGdiHandles = [Win32.NativeMethods]::GetGuiResources($p.Handle, 0)
        If ($auxGdiHandles -eq 0)                    { continue }
        $auxCountHandles += $auxGdiHandles
        $auxDict = [ordered]@{
            PID         = $p.Id
            Handles     = $auxGdiHandles
            ProcessName = $p.Name
        }
        $GuiResources += [PSCustomObject]$auxDict
}

$GuiResources  #| Sort-Object "ProcessName" #| Format-Table -AutoSize

<##> 
    ### summary debugging output ###
Write-Host $('{0} processes; {1}/{2} with/without GDI objects' -f $allProcesses.Count,
    $GuiResources.Count,
    ($allProcesses.Count - $GuiResources.Count))
Write-Host "Total number of GDI handles: $auxCountHandles`n"
<##>
```

Sample output (truncated):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> D:\PShell\tests\GdiObjectCounter.ps1

161 processes; 27/134 with/without GDI objects
Total number of GDI handles: 2642

  PID Handles ProcessName         
  --- ------- -----------         
  712      16 SettingSyncHost     
  744       6 winlogon            
 7524       7 ShellExperienceHost 
 3852      36 RuntimeBroker       
 3696      74 chrome              
…
```